# Installing Dashing on a server

Tags: ruby, dashing

I'm looking to install the Dashing framework by Shopify on an external server, such as HostGator.com.  I know Dashing runs on Ruby and you can install Ruby in the cPanel account of Hostgator servers.

My question is, one I instal Ruby on the server, how would I install Dashing onto the server as well?

Answer (score 0):

You have to run the commands listed in [Dashing Getting started](http://shopify.github.io/dashing/#setup).

Check cPanel if there is an option for console/ssh access. In general, shared webhosting services do not offer console access.

Comment: Thanks, I'll check.  If they don't offer console access, then I'll have to run it on my computer.. Where else can I run Dashing so I can access it via a url like dashboard.example.com? (a cloud service maybe?)

Comment: If you want full control of your (web)server, hire a VPS.